# Angular 2 Html Select model not matching to option value

Tags: javascript, html, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have 2 arrays out of which 1 array values are bound to select dropdown values.
On clearing of another array, I want to render only one option.
Following is the code:

### Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl : 'app/app.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  arrToClear = [1,2,3,4];
  arrToBind = ["NONE", "SOME", "OTHER"];
  modelToBind = 'NONE';

}
```

View

---

```
MODEL -> {{modelToBind}}
<button type='button'(click)="arrToClear.length = 0; modelToBind = 'NONE'">Clear Array </button>


<select class="form-control"
                            id="someId"
                            name="someName"
                            [ngModel]="modelToBind"
                            #someName="ngModel"
                            >
                      <ng-container *ngIf="arrToClear.length">
                        <option *ngFor="let data of arrToBind"
                                [ngValue]="data"> {{data}}
                        </option>
                      </ng-container>
                      <option value="NONE" *ngIf="!arrToClear.length">
                        Value
                      </option>
                    </select>
```

Problem is, when I clear "arrToClearArr" array, my selected value is empty. It should get bound to "A" because my model contains "A".

Additionally, I want only one-way binding hence I have used [ngModel].

What am I missing here? Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

[Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/oVykrz4viOoAYmICsP2t?p=preview)

---

Expected behavior:

1. Change dropdown value
2. Click 'Clear array' button
3. Dropdown value should be "A", currently, it is ""

Comment: is the correct option element displayed in the DOM?
Is Value meant to be a variable or just placeholder text for this example?

Comment: Yes, option element is correctly displayed in the DOM, and value is just a string in the example which should matched with variable used as ngModel.

Answer (score 0):

This is optional but personally I would not use the `[ngModel]` and try using Template-driven forms for this issue as I believe it would be clearer to just bind the variable directly.Just as you did with the for loop.

```
<select class="form-control" id="someId" formControlName="someName" name="someName">
  <ng-container *ngIf="arrToClear.length">
    <option *ngFor="let data of arrToBind" [value]="data"> {{data}}</option>
  </ng-container>
  <option [value]="modelToBind" *ngIf="!arrToClear.length">{{modelToBind}</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively could you not keep everything the same and just edit the last option.

```
<select class="form-control" id="someId" [ngModel]="modelToBind" #someName="ngModel" name="someName">
  <ng-container *ngIf="arrToClear.length">
    <option *ngFor="let data of arrToBind" [ngValue]="data"> {{data}}</option>
  </ng-container>
  <option [value]="modelToBind" *ngIf="!arrToClear.length">{{modelToBind}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, that works!
I have captured (change) event to get selected value and do further operations.
Can you please explain why one way binding is not working even after it's value is matched with option value?

Comment: you write 'Additionally, I want only one way binding hence I have used [ngModel]' but what you really mean is that you want two way data binding. As the solution above is one way and using ngModel is two way. But I do not really understand the need for two way for your solution.

Comment: Ok, so the reason I have used [ngModel] and not [(ngModel)] is because, whatever initial value is, that value should get binded to select. 
 Afterwords, when I change value, I do not want my modal to get updated, hence [ngModel].  
Which can also be achieved by removing ngModel completely (as per your answer) and adding (change) event to capture whatever has been selected.

Comment: Fair play, I apologise i see you are using `[ngModel]` and not `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: No probs, thanks for the solution, but the question why [ngModel] was not working in my case is still unanswered :(

Comment: got you, will try out now

Comment: Ok so ive checked everything seems `[ngModel]` is working fine and the way i have suggested to do it seems to be the standard method.

Comment: Oh, ok. Seems like whatever I was doing, was not proper. Thanks for giving proper approach.